# Why are all the normal Minions yellow in color?

Tags: despicable-me, minions

Till now we have seen that the Minions in the *Despicable Me* series and in *Minions* are yellow in color when normal. In *Despicable Me 2* they turn into Purple-furred monsters when mutated with the highly potent mutagen PX-41.

Is there any reference why they are yellow in color?

[image]

Comment: Not exactly an answer but a fun fact: "The evil Minions are purple because purple and yellow are on opposite sides of the color spectrum." ([source](http://www.despicablememinions.net/despicable-me-minions/))

Comment: @N_Soong, I think evil minions were yellow because the serum that made them evil made a living creature purple. I think the fact is regarding why the film makers chose it to be purple.

Answer (score 4):

I saw in a documentary/making-of that minions were inspired by both TicTac candies and gift-eggs from Kinder surprise, which explains the yellow color and why they are so full of surprise and always ready to have fun. That was the character designer words, (translated from french).

Comment: If this is true, could you try to find a source for the quote to support your claim?

Comment: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x10msza_moi-moche-et-mechant-2-gad-elmaleh-chez-illumination_shortfilms#.UbB_n_Vq58F

It is at 2:20, unfortunately in french, so i can be a bit more accurate now i found it back /
Yellow color is just because they"re wearing blue suits and the color was better suiting, the candy thing is about the fact they dont have a nose.

Answer (score 2):

While we may not know the specific reason for their color, we do know that they have been around for millions of years, as we see that they interact with dinosaurs. This means that they may just be yellow because that is how they evolved. Why is any animal any color?

Another theory I have is that yellow is generally seen as a happy color. And they are very happy creatures. But it is almost ironic that, even though they are such happy, loving creatures, they are always looking for someone evil to follow. So yellow is mostly a contrast to, for example, Gru, who is very into the dark color scheme.